# Solver consistency for matrix ODE

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider the matrix differential equation in PSD matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$

$$\dot X(t) = X(t) F(X(t))^T + F(X(t))X(t),$$

where $F(X):\mathbb{R}^{N \times N} \to \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is a matrix-valued function.

I wonder if I can apply the below discretization, which is a mix of the explicit and implicit Euler method, and ensure the solution to be consistent

$$\frac{X_{k+1}-X_k}{\Delta t} = X_{k+1} F(X_k)^T + F(X_k)X_{k+1}$$

Comment: Same notation for matrices and integers is confusing.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: What do you know about $F$?

Comment: Yes, you can do this, it still will give a first-order method. Why do you think this scheme is better than just the forward Euler method? Or the iteration formula $X_{k+1}=(I-F(X_k)Δt)^{-1}X_k(I-F(X_k)^TΔt)^{-T}$?